# develop on another mac

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have a certificate code sign and an app mobileprovision for a mac.

Is it possible to use the certificate and the mobileprovision file to develop in another mac?

Welcome any comment

Comment: ya. you can use the same certi and profile to develop in another mac if they are available in another mac too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To export your developer profile . . .
>
> 1. In the devices organizer, select your team in the Teams section.
> 2. Click Export.
> 3. Specify a filename and a password, and click Save.
>
> To import your developer profile . . .
>
> 1. In the devices organizer, select your team in the Teams section.
> 2. Click Import.
> 3. Select the file containing your code signing assets.
> 4. Enter the password for the file, and click Open.

from [Xcode 4 User Guide - Transfer Your Developer Profile to Another Computer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/Devices/Devices.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010215-CH12-SW16). There is more info about the process available in this document too.